# Not replacing the value in IN clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

When I run this query I am not getting the output. But When I hardcode the value to all 3 variable I am getting the desire result in cursor. How to make it run the above query?

```
PROCEDURE P_getdata(zip            IN LONG,
                    streetnumberda IN LONG,
                    apt_n          IN LONG,
                    cur            OUT C_DATA)
AS
  l_query LONG;
BEGIN
    l_query :=
'select firstname, lastname, streetname, city from mytable 
                       where zip IN(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:zip,''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUALCONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(:zip, ''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) 
                       AND streetnumber IN(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:streetnumberda,''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(:streetnumberda, ''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) 
                       AND apt_num in(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:apt_n,''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUALCONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(:apt_n, ''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)'
;

OPEN cur FOR l_query;
END;
```

parameters values are (all are varchar)

```
           a ='202020';
           b='12','13','10','92','02','02'
           c='A','B'
```

Comment: your bind variables are not bound.

Answer (score 2):

You must supply arguments for all placeholders in your query.
The placeholder is a parameter preceded with `:` character, for example: `:zip`, `:apt_n`

More on using placeholders (with examples) you can find ehere
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#BHCGEFCA

The query in your question has 6 placeholders:

> select firstname, lastname, streetname, city from mytable 
>   where zip IN(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(**:zip**,''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUALCONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(**:zip**, ''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) 
>                          AND streetnumber IN(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(**:streetnumberda**,''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(**:streetnumberda**, ''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) 
>                          AND apt_num in(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(**:apt_n**,''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUALCONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(**:apt_n**, ''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)'
>   ;

therefore you must provide 6 bind parameters after `USING` keyword:

```
OPEN cur FOR l_query USING zip, zip, streetnumberda, streetnumberda, apt_n, apt_n;
```

---

I've tested your code and it worked, below is my code snippet.
Could be that the problem in your code is here: `FROM DUALCONNECT BY` - there is missing space between DUAL and CONNECT BY.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
  firstname varchar2(100), lastname varchar2(100), streetname varchar2(100), city varchar2(100),
  zip varchar2(100), streetnumber varchar2(100), apt_num  varchar2(100))
;

insert into mytable values('FNAME','LNAME','STREET','CITY','202020','12','A' );

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_getdata(zip  IN LONG,
                    streetnumberda IN LONG,
                    apt_n          IN LONG,
                    cur            OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
  l_query LONG;
BEGIN
    l_query :=
    q'[select firstname, lastname, streetname, city from mytable 
     where zip IN(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:zip,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUAL
                  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(:zip, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) 
       AND streetnumber IN(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:streetnumberda,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUAL 
                           CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(:streetnumberda, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) 
       AND apt_num in(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:apt_n,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUAL
                      CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(:apt_n, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)]';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_query );
  OPEN cur FOR l_query USING zip, zip, streetnumberda, streetnumberda, apt_n, apt_n;
END; 
/

DECLARE
   cur sys_refcursor;
   fname varchar2(100); lname varchar2(100); strname varchar2(100); city varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  P_getdata('202020','12,13,10,92,02,02', 'A,B', cur );
  LOOP
     FETCH cur INTO fname, lname, strname, city;
     EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( fname||'--'||lname||'--'||strname||'--'||city );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: still the query is not replaced by the parameters

Comment: Please check, I have posted the paramter

Comment: I've tested your code and it worked, please take a look at my code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

open cur for  select firstname, lastname, streetname, city
           from mytable 
           where zip (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(A,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(A, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
   AND streetnumber IN(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(B,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(B, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
   AND apt_num in(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(C,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(C, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL

It is working